# Ditto - exclude a child from a parent

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

How to exclude a specific child resource from Ditto call. From parent 55, I want to exclude child resource 28.

```
 [!Ditto? 
      &parents=`2,55` 
      &depth=`1` 
      &tpl=`base` 
      &paginate=`1` 
      &display=`5` 
      &orderBy=`date`
 !]
```

Comment: Why are you add `modx-revo` tag if your question is only for `modx-evo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use a filter to removed unwanted IDs 
[check the docs](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/evo/ditto/ditto-parameters)

the docs outline the format, it should be:

```
&filter=`id,28,2`
```

Comment: I tried to use &filter=`28`, but that doesnt work because before I already specified the parent in &parents. So the filter is ignored... :(